# AutoComplete Location Selection Box in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

All the material that I can find online on this topic uses Bing Location API and Bing Map Controls. But the recent SDK have native Maps support in the `Microsoft.Phone.Maps` namespace. What is the easiest way to implement a AutoComplete Location Selection Box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible: Yes

Efficient: No

There is no AutoComplete Location Selection Box kind of control in Windows Phone sdk But, That can be imitated by making a textbox and subscribing to its TextChanged events, and calling the service to ReverseGeoCode the text provided in the textbox in the event.

Something like this

```
    private void tbxPlayerTwoName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Start reverseGeoCoding
    }
```

But as said above the solution would not be smooth enough to be called as UserFriendly